# Implicit derivative of $x^2+x\arcsin(y)=ye^x$

Tags: calculus, inverse-function, implicit-differentiation

Find the implicit derivative of:

$$x^2+x\arcsin(y)=ye^x$$

So taking the derivative results in the function becoming

$$2x+\frac{y^{'}x}{\sqrt{1^2-y^2}}+\arcsin(y)=y^{'}e^x+ye^x$$
Moving all the terms with $y^{'}$to one side gives us

$$\frac{y^{'}x}{\sqrt{1^2-y^2}}-y^{'}e^x=ye^x-2x-\arcsin(y)$$
then factoring out $y^{'}$get us to
$$y^{'}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1^2-y^2}}-e^x\right)=ye^x-2x-\arcsin(y)$$
Solving for $y^{'}$ 
$$y^{'}=\frac{\left(2x+arcsin(y)-ye^x\right) \sqrt{1-y^2}}{{e^x\sqrt{1-y^2}-x}}$$

Comment: First you have: $$y'=\dfrac{ye^x-2x-\arcsin(y)}{\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}-e^x}$$ Multiply numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{1-y^2}$ gives: $$y'=\frac{ye^x-2x-\arcsin(y)}{x-e^x\sqrt{1-y^2}}\sqrt{1-y^2}$$

Comment: Yeah so I didn't realize that my teacher had another section of answers that are also correct for the practice problems, I'll edit the post to reflect this.

Comment: Your edited final answer is still slightly incorrect, I believe. The sign of $\arcsin(y)$ in the numerator should be positive and you should put parenthesis around the expression $2x + \arcsin(y) - ye^x$.

Comment: After your edit, you are correct up to 

$$y^{'}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1^2-y^2}}-e^x\right)=ye^x-2x-\arcsin(y)$$

to solve for $y'$, divide both sides by $\frac{x}{\sqrt{1^2-y^2}}-e^x$ to form

$$y^{'}=\frac{ye^x-2x-\arcsin(y)}{\frac{x}{\sqrt{1^2-y^2}}-e^x}$$

and then multiply the numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{1^2-y^2}$ to form

$$y^{'}=\frac{ye^x-2x-\arcsin(y)}{x-e^x\sqrt{1^2-y^2}}\sqrt{1^2-y^2}$$